# 進捗バーを拡大し色を変更したい

Tags: html, wordpress

wordpressのブログ内で進捗バーを使用したいのですが、このままではなく拡大し色を変え使用したいです。

```
<progress value="20" max="100">20 %</progress>
```

情報が少なかったのですが、可能でしょうか。

ご教授いただけば幸いです、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 拡大

`background-color`を指定すると `height`が反映される様です。
（バー色の指定方法は未だ知りません）

```css
#p1 {
    height: 6px;
    width:500px;
    background-color: #28cc50;
}
#p2 {
    height: 13px;
    width:400px;
    background-color: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<progress id="p1" value="70" max="100" >70%</progress><br>
<progress id="p2" value="70" max="100" >70%</progress>
```

Comment: yyZ様。ご回答ありがとうございました。無事使用することができました。わたしも引き続き調査し何か進展がありましたらまたここにご報告させていただきます。今回は誠にありがとうございました。